# Calling WSO2 APIs from other application is showing error "sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed"

Tags: java, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am trying to call WSO2 APIs for creating new user in WSO2 Identity Server. The WSO2 API is as below:
When calling the service using Java, I am getting an error as described below:

```
curl -v -k --user admin:admin --data "{"schemas":[],"name": { "familyName":"family_name","givenName":"given_name"},"userName":"user_name","password":"pass_word", "emails":[{"primary":true,"value":"im@example.net","type":"work"},{"primary":false,"value":"im2@gmail.com","type":"home"} ] }" --header "ContentType:application/json" https://localhost:9443/wso2/scim/Users
```

The Error messages is :

> Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
> sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
> sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
> find valid certification path to requested target     at
> sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)  at
> sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1946)     at
> sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:316)  at
> sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:310)  at
> sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1640)
> at
> sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:223)
> at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1037)    at
> sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:965)   at
> sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1064)    at
> sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1367)
> at
> sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1395)
> at
> sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1379)
> at
> org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:436)
> at
> org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:384)
> at
> org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
> at
> org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:376)
> at
> org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:393)
> at
> org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
> at
> org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
> at
> org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
> at
> org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
> at
> org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
> at
> org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
> at
> org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
> at
> org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ManualClosingApacheHttpClient43Engine.invoke(ManualClosingApacheHttpClient43Engine.java:268)

---

I have created a keystore file(client.keystore) and copied inside src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/ folder but still the issue is persisting.
Please suggest a way to solve this issue if anyone faces it.

Comment: The error you get is a certifcate validation error. Did you register the certifacte or any of its "parents" (like intermediate or root ca) with your runtime using keytool?

Comment: The client.keystore file is generated using keytool and placed inside META-INF/resources/ folder of my application.

Comment: You have to find what's the client truststore used from your application and add the WSO2 Identity Server SSL certificate to that truststore. How did you identify the client.keystore file is the truststore code is using? and how did you generate this client.keystore file?

Comment: Please find the steps which I am following for creating keystore and truststore files in below:

Comment: Step 1) keytool -genkeypair -storepass password -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -dname "CN=server" -alias server -ext "SAN:c=DNS:localhost,IP:127.0.0.1" -keystore /ISIntegrationProj/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/client.keystore

Comment: Step 2) keytool -genkeypair -storepass password -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -dname "CN=client" -alias client -ext "SAN:c=DNS:localhost,IP:127.0.0.1" -keystore /IdentityServerWso2/2IS/usr/lib64/wso2/wso2is/5.10.0/repository/resources/security/server.keystore

Comment: Step 3) cp /IdentityServerWso2/2IS/usr/lib64/wso2/wso2is/5.10.0/repository/resources/security/server.keystore /ISIntegrationProj//src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/client.truststore

Comment: Step 4) cp /ISIntegrationProj/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/client.keystore /IdentityServerWso2/2IS/usr/lib64/wso2/wso2is/5.10.0/repository/resources/security/server.truststore

Comment: Still the issue is there. The respective error messages is: 
RESTEASY004655: Unable to invoke request: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Comment: @maduranga-siriwardena What is the issue in the keystore and truststore files which are created using the above steps? Is there any documentation available in wsp2 docs site? Please share

Comment: Issue is solved now.